# Deep serialization and export Django

Tags: django, filter, foreign-keys

Let's say that I have these classes :

```
ClassA(models.Model):
    is_important = True
    information_about_something = models.ForeignKey("ClassB")
    information_about_something_else = models.ForeignKey("ClassB")
    url_about_thing = models.ForeignKey("ClassC")
    url_about_something_else = models.ForeignKey("ClassC")


ClassD(models.Model):
    is_important = True
    an_information = models.ForeignKey("ClassB")
    foo = models.ForeignKey("ClassC")
```

And now, I'm filtering these classes like :

```
importantStuff = ClassA.objects.filter(is_important = True) + ClassD.objects.filter(is_important = True)
```

How to follow all foreign keys on this list ? For instance :

```
all_items_from_classB = all_items_from_classC = []
for item in importantStuff:
    all_items_from_classB = item.followForeignKey("ClassB")
    # idem for classC
```

Is there an "elegant" way to do so ? 
Thanks

**ADDED INFORMATIONS**

To be more specific, it's about an authentication manager based on OAuth, here are my classes :

```
class AuthManager(models.Model):
    token_key = models.ForeignKey("Information")
    token_secret = models.ForeignKey("Information")
    client_key = models.ForeignKey("Information")
    client_secret = models.ForeignKey("Information")

class Information(models.Model):
    identifier = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    # Other fields
```

Now, let's suppose that I have my AuthManagers with

```
am = AuthManager.objects.all()
```

I want to get all the `Information` objects related to these `AuthManager`, regardless of if it's a `token_key`, `token_secret` ...

Such as `Information.objects.get_elements_related_to(am)`

Comment: not sure what do you really want, because if you will select `AuthManager.objects.select_related()` it will create one big query where all of the data from `AuthManager` and all fields will be fetched by one SQL.